# replace comma with whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

my input:`(((text(text here))) AND (test3) Near (test4) NOT (test5) NOT (Test6)),((tttt,tttt)),((and,lol)),((hbhbhbhbhbh))`

my ouput:`(((text(text here))) AND (test3) Near (test4) NOT (test5) NOT (Test6) (tttt,tttt) (and,lol) (hbhbhbhbhbh))`

the result that I expected:`(((text(text here))) AND (test3) Near (test4) NOT (test5) NOT (Test6) ((tttt,tttt)) ((and,lol)) ((hbhbhbhbhbh))`

I want to replace the comma with whitespace when I have this string `),(`

**DEMO:**

```js
 var txt="(((text(text here))) AND (test3) Near (test4) NOT (test5) NOT (Test6)),((tttt,tttt)),((and,lol)),((hbhbhbhbhbh))"
  var finalResult=txt.replace(/[)],[(]/g," ");

console.log("Result:",finalResult);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be including the `)(` in your result:

```js
var txt = "(((text(text here))) AND (test3) Near (test4) NOT (test5) NOT (Test6)),((tttt,tttt)),((and,lol)),((hbhbhbhbhbh))"
var finalResult = txt.replace(/[)],[(]/g, ") (");

console.log("Result:", finalResult);
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Result: (((text(text here))) AND (test3) Near (test4) NOT (test5) NOT (Test6)) ((tttt,tttt)) ((and,lol)) ((hbhbhbhbhbh))
```

Also, note that you don't need a `.toString()` function here as the original `txt` is a type of String.

Comment: Perfect Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenKumar no need to use `toString()`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Yeah I know it, just changed the regex part for the OP. `:)`

Comment: @MokiNex You don't need to use `.toString()`. It's unnecessary here. Just FYI. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just commented for you to edit and improve the solution

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Improved. Thanks.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes I know but I just add tostring because in reality my input is a list of string

Comment: Ha ha... OKay... Sure... `:)`

Comment: @MokiNex Have a nice day! `:D`